# IE image width & height = 0 before image downloaded

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web

I'm trying to set the width & height property of an image element i've created in javascript. In FF, Opera & Chrome it's sets the width & height correctly. However in IE 6 & 7 (Haven't tried 8) the width & height remain 0 until the image is downloaded. The reason I need this is so that i can position each image in rows & cols based on it's current size.

If it's not possible to set the width & height properties in IE I think i'll just have to create my own custom property and set it in there.

Here is the basic code i'm using to create & inject the element.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
var wrap = document.createElement('div');

document.body.appendChild(wrap);
wrap.appendChild(img);

img.src = 'blah.jpg';
img.width = '100';
img.height = '100';
img.style.display = 'none';

// IE: width: 0 | height: 0
// FF: width: 100 | height: 100
alert('width: ' + img.width + ' | height: ' + img.height);
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried setting img.style.visibility = 'hidden' instead of img.style.display='none'; but it doesn't make a difference.

**EDIT**

I found the issue. The actual problem was a combination of Aziz solution and something I left out in the original example. It appears that in IE if you append the element inside another element before assigning a width & height IE just ignores it.

Comment: How are you creating the image? What does the markup look like?

http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I've added the skeleton of the code that i'm using.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate on IE6/IE7 with the code you've given. I've even tried large images to ensure the alert happens before the image loads. The alert shows the proper width/height for me.

Comment: Sorry I left the display: none out. I also tried the visibilty: hidden the Aziz mentioned but It's still the same problem.

Comment: Could there be any other relevant code missing? Visibility hidden worked for me.

Comment: @Alex .. try the code I posted .. it works with me

Comment: I tried the code supplied and it does work. When I try to do the same in my original it doesn't work :(

It's a massive code base so I can't post it all here. The image is positioned in heaps of nested elements and is absolutely positioned. Would that make a difference?

Comment: I changed the `img.style.display = 'none';` to `img.style.visibility = 'hidden';` , which makes it work in IE. It should work in any position\nesting .. etc as long as it is kept as `<img>` tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This problem is explained here](http://jimdiesel.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/javasvript-image-dimension-issue-in-internet-explorer/)

In order to get the correct dimensions in IE, you need to set **<strike>`display: hidden`</strike> `visibility: hidden`**. However, you have to make sure you set it only if the browser is IE.

**Edit**
try this (works for me)

```
var img = document.createElement('img');

img.src = 'blah.jpg';
img.width = '3000';
img.height = '1000';

img.style.visibility = 'hidden';


document.body.appendChild(img);

// should work correctly
alert('width: ' + img.width + ' | height: ' + img.height);
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need the unit:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');

img.src = 'blah.jpg';
img.style.display = 'none';
img.style.width = '100px';
img.style.height = '100px';

document.body.appendChild(img);

// IE: width: 100 | height: 100
// FF: width: 100 | height: 100
alert('width: ' + img.style.width + ' | height: ' + img.style.height);
```

Remember to add the unit "px". Use `element.style.width` and `element.style.height` instead of `element.width` and `element.height` respectively for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: I have tested  element.style.height  and element.style.width properties and works perfectly  on Opera, Firefox, IE 11 and Chrome. but element.height and element.width doesnt work correctly on all cross browser